# Attempting to make a Integer to Binary Converter in C, however it just prints random strings

Tags: c

I'm learning C at the moment and was making a Denary to Binary converter in C, and have come across this problem I just can't fix

```
// Includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef enum {false,true} bool;

// intToBinary Function
char* intToBinary(int d)
{
    bool not0 = true;

    char* outputstr = "";

    while(not0 == true)
    {
        int d = floor(d/2);

        int rem = d % 2;

        char num = rem;

        outputstr += (char)num;

        if(d==0)
        {
            printf("%s\n",outputstr);
            return outputstr;
        }
    }
}

// Main Function
int main()
{
    int inp;
    printf("Enter A Number To Be Converted\n");
    scanf("%d", &inp);

    char* out = (char*)intToBinary(inp);

    printf(out);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure why, but the only outputs I get are:
r To Be Converted
&
r To Be Converted(It repeats itself)

i'm compiling using msys on Windows 10

if you know what i've done wrong, could you tell me.
Thanks

Comment: `outputstr += (char)num;` probably doesn't do what you expect it to, it adds to the pointer.

Comment: `char num = rem` itself seems fishy.  rem is 0 or 1, which `char` can be set to, but those aren't th ascii / unicode values for the `0` or `0` characters.  You need to add `'0'` to the value to achieve that.  `char num = '0' + rem`

Comment: Not only does the function not return a value from all control paths, but it returns a pointer to what began as a string literal of length 0. You can't modify a string literal, nor can you increase an array length without using dynamic memory.

Comment: Please take notice of compiler warnings too: one is for `int d = floor(d/2);` which says you are using an uninitiliased value. The reason is you have defined *another variable `d`* with the same name as the function argument (it is called a "shadow variable"). Apart from the unnecessary use of `floor` (because integer division is truncated anyway), please remove `int`, so it reads `d = d / 2;`

Comment: Also `stdbool.h` defines `bool` and `false` and `true`.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to learn C by by guessing how things work and trying out stuff. This might not be the best method. You probably want to get a C textbook. Read a chapter about strings and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`char* outputstr = "";`

You should not modify this string at all. It resides in implementation defined read only region. Modifying it causes Undefined Behavior.

You need a char array not a string literal.

Good Read:
What is the difference between char a[] = "string"; and char *p = "string";

Try this:

```
// Includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef enum {false,true} bool;

char * append(char * string1, char * string2)
{
    char * string3 = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(string1)+strlen(string2) );
    strcpy(string3, string1);
    strcat(string3, string2);
    return string3;
}

// intToBinary Function
char* intToBinary(int d)
{
    bool not0 = true;

    char* outputstr = "";

    while(not0 == true)
    {
        d = d/2;

        int rem = d % 2;

        char num = (char)(rem+48);

        char *s = &num;

        outputstr = append(outputstr, s);


        if(d==0)
        {
            printf("%s\n",outputstr);
            return outputstr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for the advice. I made the corrections.

Comment: The code doesn't work, did you test it? In particular, `num` is not a string.

Comment: `typedef enum {false,true} bool;` - Wouldn't `#include <stdbool.h>` be simpler? `char *s = &num;` - num is not a pointer to a string, `strlen(string2)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: This code has memory leaks, undefined behaviour, logic errors, and bad style.